# Windows Phone application can not debug on real device

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7

I've developed an application for Windows Phone, and it runs well on emulator. But I want to debug the application on my phone, the samsung Omnia 7, so I changed the target from "Windows Phone Emulator" to "Windows Phone Device" in Visual Studio 2010, and hit the run button.

Then I got the error message says: "The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

Well, I DID unlock the screen and actually, the application IS installed on my device, but the only problem is that, I can not debug it.

I've been googling around, but no good. And the OS version of my rom is 7.10.7720.68, I'm using Omnia 7, which has already been verified with my developer ID.

Anyone encountered with the same situation? Any advice?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried using the USB connect tool?

Comment: Are you sure your phone is still dev-unlocked? It automatically relocks itself after one year.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need confirm did you run Zune Application and make sure your Windows phone Device have connected status then click debug button.

second。if have been set password about your start screen. when get be debuy operator before you need make your deveice at Start Screen。

three。 debug Windows phone it was need you have use Developer Account have unlock your Device already.

there all core three step。，